# HeidiSQL solution for SQL Server error 18488?

Tags: sql-server, tools, sql-server-tools

I'm connecting to a remote database using HeidiSQL client but looks like the administrator has activated the enforce password change policy (Error 18488).

Is there a workaround to solve this with HeidiSQL? Or I need to download and install SQL Server Management Studio?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the password from [`sqlcmd`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) using `-z` or `-Z`:

> -z new_password Change password:
>
> ```
> sqlcmd -U someuser -P s0mep@ssword -z a_new_p@a$$w0rd
> ```
>
> -Z new_password Change password and exit:
>
> ```
> sqlcmd -U someuser -P s0mep@ssword -Z a_new_p@a$$w0rd
> ```